# How do I create Long Press menu on RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android

I have created 50 relative layouts dynamically in "**MainActivity.java**".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     RelativeLayout big=new RelativeLayout(this);
     RelativeLayout mini;
     setContentView(big);
     for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
     {
         //just a sample example. Accept that the code is completely correct.

         mini=new RelativeLayout(this);
         big.addView(mini);
     }
  }
}
```

Now, I want, when each "**mini**" is long pressed a pop up or context menu will appear containing two options (1.Open and 2.Hide). This, Open/Hide actions will be done by me when one is chosen.

I searched internet and found some suggestions to create a ***.xml** in menu directiory and attach to **MainActivity.java** using **onCreateContextMenu** event.

But, i didn't understand that. As I am new in adnroid, please give me the full code to create context menu when long pressed on a view with instructions (like "add **menu_all.xml** to **menu** directory", "create new **.*java** file" etc.)

**N.B. The app I want to build at API 19.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
registerForContextMenu(mini);
```

This func take a view as an Argument and generates the context menu for you.

Override the onCreateContextMenu func of your activity and do whatever you want to do.

Here's a sample code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    ListView listView1;  
    String contacts[]={"Ajay","Sachin","Sumit","Tarun","Yogesh"};  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);  
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);  
        // Register the ListView  for Context menu  
        registerForContextMenu(listView1);  
    }  
    @Override   
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
    {  
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call");//groupId, itemId, order, title   
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "SMS");   
    }   
    @Override    
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
            if(item.getTitle()=="Call"){  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }    
            else if(item.getTitle()=="SMS"){  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sending sms code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }else{  
               return false;  
            }    
          return true;    
      }    
    }
```

Comment: i have done this like you described. (under onCreate Event)
But getting many errors= "Method does not override its method from its SuperClass", "Cannot resolve symbol "ContextMenu""
what should I do?